# Insert cookie value to get variable?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, cookies, get

I have a PHP link `example.com/?dir=en&text=mytext` Is it possible to put in the `"text="` the cookie value `GetCookie('MyCookie1');` and then open the link in new tab? 
I imagine that I have to:

1. Get cookie value.
2. `document.getElementById("phplink").setAttribute("onClick", "//example.com/?dir=en&text= GetCookie('MyCookie1');");`

I have tried the above method, but no success :(

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're getting a big mixed up between client side (javascript/DOM) and server side (PHP) programming. Can you rephrase your question to clarify?

Comment: I wrote exactly what is my question. And it ts simple. Just to add th cookie value to a link. Maybe throw html form with hidden parametres?

Comment: It may be obvious to you what you want to do, but for example you don't specify where this "PHP link" is coming from, or why you're using JavaScript. If all you want to do is add the value of a cookie to a link, you can just do: $link .= $_COOKIE['MyCookie1'];